# Get data from tables without foreign key

Tags: join, inner-join, cross-join

I need help with a query to fetch data from 3 tables, as given below.

Table T1 - has tID as the primary key
Table T2 - TID is the foreign key in this table
Table T3 - rname is equal to rname in t2 but these two tables are not related.

I have tried using inner join which doesn't give the desired result (shows the same value of SREF across all rows) and Cross join generates a product.

Can you please help so that I get the output given in the desired output section.

Thanks

Gagan

create table t1 (tID,  ts,   Val) as select
1, to_date('2/2/2015 12:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  1  from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2  from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2  from dual union all select
1,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:10', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  1  from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:10', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2  from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:10', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2  from dual union all select
1,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  null  from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  3  from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2  from dual union all select
1,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:20', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  null from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:20', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  1 from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:20', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  3 from dual union all select
1,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:25', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  null from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:25', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  10 from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:25', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  9 from dual union all select
1,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:30', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  1 from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:30', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2 from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:30', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  1 from dual union all select
1,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:35', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  null from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:35', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2 from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:35', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  1 from dual union all select
1,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:40', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  null from dual union all select
2,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:40', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2 from dual union all select
3,   to_date('2/2/2015 12:40', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),  2 from dual;

create table t2 (tID, sname,   rname) as select
1, SN1, RN1 from dual union all select
2, SN2, RN2 from dual union all select
3, SN3, RN3 from dual union all select
4, SN4, RN4 from dual union all select
5, SN5, RN5 from dual union all select
6, SN6, RN6 from dual union all select
7, SN7, RN7 from dual union all select
8, SN8, RN8 from dual union all select
9, SN9, RN9 from dual union all select
10, SN10, RN10 from dual;

create table t3 (rid, rname, sref) as select
R1, RN1, SREF1 from dual union all select
R2, RN2, SREF2 from dual union all select
R3, RN3, SREF3 from dual union all select
R4, RN4, SREF4 from dual union all select
R5, RN5, SREF5 from dual union all select
R6, RN6, SREF6 from dual union all select
R7, RN7, SREF7 from dual union all select
R8, RN8, SREF8 from dual union all select
R9, RN9, SREF9 from dual union all select
R10, RN10, SREF10 from dual;

Output desired

TID, SNAME, RNAME, SREF1
1, SN1, RN1, SREF1
2, SN2, RN2, SREF2
3, SN3, RN3, SREF3

Comment: Please show your attempt at a join - that's exactly what you should do, chances are you've just missed something.

Comment: This the query I wrote  SELECT
T1."TID" AS TID,  T2."SNAME" AS SNAME, T2."RNAME" AS RNAME,T3."SREF" AS SREF
FROM
     "SDB"."T1” T1 INNER JOIN "SDB"."T2" T2 ON T1."T_ID" = T2."TID"
     INNER JOIN "SDB"."T3" T3 ON T2."RNAME" = T3."RNAME"

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: "Table T1 - has tID as the primary key Table T2 - TID is the foreign key in this table", but in the example it's the other way around.

You wrote: "Table T3 - sname is equal to sname in t2 but these two tables are not related.", but there is no sname in T3

Did you try:
`select t1.TID, t2.SNAME, t2.RNAME, t3.SREF from t1,t2,t3 where t1.tid=t2.tid and t2.rname=t3.rname`

Comment: Sorry, my bad T2 and T3 have rname in common. I tried the query you have provided but it gives the same value of sref against all the rows

Comment: The select I provided gives this result (Oracle):
`TID,SNAME,RNAME,SREF
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3
1,SN1,RN1,SREF1
2,SN2,RN2,SREF2
3,SN3,RN3,SREF3`